# raml 0.8 and using traits for message body

Tags: traits, raml

I am using RAML 0.8, and I am trying to use/understand traits

I have an api design that I can see several fields are repeated in the message body for each api call. and my reading of the raml spec, is that as these are repeatable, they should be a candidate for a trait

```
/kmi/for/{product}:
  uriParameters: 
    product: 
      description: |
        The product that want to be informed about
      required: true
      repeat: false
      type: string
      example: beans
  post:
    description: |
      Used to submit a keep me informed request
    body:
      application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
        formParameters:
          title:
            description: ...
            type: string
            required: false
            repeat: false
            example: Mr
          firstname:
            description: ...
            type: string
            required: true
            repeat: false
            example: John
          lastname:
            description: ...
            type: string
            required: true
            repeat: false
            example: Connor
          emailAddress:
            description: ...
            type: string
            required: true
            repeat: false
            example: john.connor@sky.net
```

Now what I want to do is extract the form fields, title, firstname, lastname, emailAddress into a trait.

I initially tried the following

```
traits:
  - minimumFormFields:
      title:
        description: ...
        type: string
            ....
      firstname:
        description: ...
        type: string
            ....
      lastname:
        description: ...
        type: string
            ....
      emailAddress:
        description: ...
        type: string
            ....
```

and added in the trait ( extra fields removed for simplicity )

```
/kmi/for/{product}:
  post:
    description: |
      ...
    body:
      application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
        formParameters:
          is: [minimumFormFields]
```

However, that was giving me errors:

> RAML 0.8 does not allow using 'title' property within traits

I tried updating the trait to include more from the original definition, but nothing I did appears to work

```
traits:
  - minimumFormFields:
      application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
        formParameters:
          title:
            description: ...
            type: string
            ....
          firstname:
            description: ...
            type: string
            ....
          lastname:
            description: ...
            type: string
            ....
          emailAddress:
            description: ...
            type: string
            ....
```

But this gives me the following error

> [error] Unknown node: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

If I then include the body in the trait, then I get the following error

> [error] Unknown node: '' [error] Unrecognized trait:
>   'minimumFormFields'.

How can I extract fields that are submitted as part of the message body to a trait?

Our company has standardized on RAML 0.8, so I cannot upgrade to RAML 1.

** *** UPDATE 1 *** **

Reviewing the comments from Petru Gardea I created a resource type

```
resourceTypes: 
  minimumFormFields:
    post?:
      body:
        application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
          formParameters:
            title:
              description: ...
              type: string
              required: true
              repeat: false
```

But I am still getting errors

> [error] Node: 'minimumFormFields' should be wrapped in sequence
>   [error] Unknown node: 'minimumFormFields'

Changing to
-minimumFormFields:

> [error] Node: '-minimumFormFields' should be wrapped in sequence
>   [error] Unknown node: '-minimumFormFields'

Changing to
- minimumFormFields:

> [error] Unknown node: ''

I am using mulesoft.com for editing my RAML

Comment: Did you try to load the sample I've provided in my answer into your editor? If the sample I've provided doesn't work in your editor, reach out to Mulesoft to have their editor fixed. Alternatively, you can create another question showing a minimal RAML example based on my example which doesn't work in your editor, and I can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Hi, I tried your example, and this works, so I guess the error must be somewhere else. I will try again

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve what you want with traits. Instead, you need to employ resourceTypes.

This is a possible approach, showing you how it could work. The meaning of the resources is as follows:

- /kmi/test/1: Even though it is of the minimumFormFields type, since it doesn't define a post, it won't "inherit" it from the resourceType (notice the ? after post, which makes it optional);
- /kmi/test/2: defined as a reference, as per your original post
- /kmi/test/3: shows that you can even override/add from the "base" type.
- /kmi/for/{product}: clean setup, as per your requirements.

It always help to have the ability to "visualize" the "resolved" contract. A RAML parser should do this for you. The screenshots following the RAML should be self explanatory.

```
#%RAML 0.8
---
title: Sample
resourceTypes: 
  - minimumFormFields:
      post?:      
        body:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:   
            formParameters:
              title:
                description: ...
                type: string
                required: false
                repeat: false
                example: Mr
              firstname:
                description: ...
                type: string
                required: true
                repeat: false
                example: John
              lastname:
                description: ...
                type: string
                required: true
                repeat: false
                example: Connor
              emailAddress:
                description: ...
                type: string
                required: true
                repeat: false
                example: john.connor@sky.net            

/kmi/test/1:
  type: minimumFormFields
  uriParameters: 
    product: 
      description: |
        The product that want to be informed about
      required: true
      repeat: false
      type: string
      example: beans
  get:
    description: |
      Doens't show a POST
/kmi/test/2:
  post:
    description: |
      Used to submit a keep me informed request
    body:
      application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
        formParameters:
          title:
            description: ...
            type: string
            required: false
            repeat: false
            example: Mr
          firstname:
            description: ...
            type: string
            required: true
            repeat: false
            example: John
          lastname:
            description: ...
            type: string
            required: true
            repeat: false
            example: Connor
          emailAddress:
            description: ...
            type: string
            required: true
            repeat: false
            example: john.connor@sky.net        
/kmi/for/{product}:
  type: minimumFormFields
  uriParameters: 
    product: 
      description: |
        The product that want to be informed about
      required: true
      repeat: false
      type: string
      example: beans
  post:
    description: |
      Used to submit a keep me informed request
/kmi/test/3:
  type: minimumFormFields
  uriParameters: 
    product: 
      description: |
        The product that want to be informed about
      required: true
      repeat: false
      type: string
      example: beans
  post:
    description: |
      Used to submit a keep me informed request      
    body:
      application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
        formParameters:
          anotherThing:
            description: ...
            type: string
            required: false
            repeat: false
            example: Mr
          emailAddress:
            description: This looks better
            type: string
            required: true
            repeat: false
            example: johnny.connor@sky.net
```

**Test 1**: POST is removed, showing only a GET

[image]

**Test 2**: The "inlined" way.

[image]

**Test 3**: The "reused" way.

[image]

**Test 4**: The "overridden" way.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am still having problems and I have updated the original questions. FYI I am using anypoint.mulesoft.com as my RAML editor.